# Нужна ли запятая в данном придаточном?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы, спп, придаточное-предложение

**Причина в том, что когда в обществе много музыки — общество цельное.**
Нужна ли запятая после «музыки»?
*Когда в обществе много музыки, то общество цельное* — так лучше?
И еще, в школе на уроках русского языка учили: если придаточное можно изъять без потери смысла всего предложения, значит, оно обособляется с двух сторон. Это всегда верно?

Answer (score 3):

Слова японского дирижера Казуки Ямады в [**статье**](https://rg.ru/2021/04/13/kazuki-iamada-predstavil-mirovuiu-premeru-tobolskih-careven.html) выглядят так.

Под фотографией:
**Казуки Ямада: Я думаю, что когда в обществе много музыки — общество цельное.**

В тексте:
**Казуки Ямада: Думаю, причина в том, что когда в обществе много музыки — общество цельное.**

Мне кажется, что все хорошо в этих предложениях.

Повтор слова "общество" в контексте статьи вполне уместен.

Авторское тире поставлено на месте пропущенного **то** (второй части двойного союза). В этом случае при прочтении нужна выразительная пауза (чего обычной запятой не добиться), а вот перемещение или изъятие придаточной части (*что когда в обществе много музыки*) уже невозможно.
Саму же запятую поглотило тире — как более сильный знак.

[Запятая на стыке двух союзов](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=140)

Comment: Согласен, я бы тоже "препинался" так.

Comment: Благодарю за поддержку, Саша-Стрелец (помню, Вы одобрили такое обращение). _Поразнообразничаем_ маленько.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы написала примерно так:

***Причина в том, что общество становится цельным (целостным), внутренне единым, самодостаточным,  когда в нем много музыки.***

Причина правки

Вариант с обособлением и тире выглядит некрасиво, повтор слова «общество» не кажется обоснованным, а варианта со словом «то» (тогда можно не обособлять придаточное) тоже не подходит, так как уже есть местоимение «в том».

Синоним можно выбрать, но желательно использовать, так как в этом случае лучше выражена мысль и все предложение кажется более уравновешенным.

Comment: Это слова одного японского музыканта...

Comment: Музыканту принадлежат все слова, меня интересует "причина в том, что" Может быть, цитату можно использовать? Это же перевод в любом случае.

Comment: Да, Вы правы, перевод...

Comment: Причина в том, что "когда в обществе много музыки – общество цельное". Но, может быть,  надо указывать автора? Тире здесь можно поставить.

Comment: Sharon, поддерживаю ваши рассуждения и исправления текста. Но вот после комментария об одном музыканте возникает мысль о цитате –  разговорной речи, которую нужно оформить. Тогда получается, что японец в совершенстве владеет русским?

Comment: Получается, что да, владеет в совершенстве. Нужно контекст видеть, если мы хотим использовать цитату. Вообще-то они ссылаются на японца или нет. Наверное, лучше пересказать без цитирования, приблизительно.

Comment: Ваш вариант смысл сохраняет, я думаю, его мысль...

Comment: Да, как-то надо найти компромиссное решение.

Comment: Еще интереснее стало. Захотелось подумать о пунктуации именно этого предложения (из вопроса) без какого-либо контекста... домыслить самому...

Comment: Это неразрешимая задача, но, может быть, у вас получится выбраться из лабиринта...

Comment: Речь идет о том, почему японцам так нравится классическая музыка....Дальше он (музыкант) говорит, что музыка – это прекрасный способ объединения людей в обществе...

Comment: Может быть, так: ...музыка - прекрасный способ объединения людей в обществе, оно становится цельным, когда в нем много музыки.

Comment: О причине чего все-таки идет речь?

Comment: Вероятно,  "причина в том, что" - это уже пересказ его слов, поэтому можно  как-то изменить вводный текст.  Японцы любят классическую музыку,  так как музыка..."

Answer (score 0):

Ну, во-первых, в вопросе цельности общества музыка не является определяющих фактором(что бы не значило сочетание «цельность общества»).
Во-вторых, нужна запятая после «что», так как это «что» относится к «общество цельное».
В-третьих, после «музыки» нужна запятая, дабы не относить последующее предложение к придаточному времени: «когда в обществе много музыки», а относить его к: «причина в том».
В-четвертых, тире можно оставить, так как предложение довольно пафосное и произносится выразительно.
В итоге: «Причина в том, что, когда в обществе много музыки, – общество цельное».

Comment: ...причина в том, что общество цельное, это когда в нем много музыки....Тогда точно надо отделять... «когда в обществе много музыки» вклинилось

Comment: Я не понял, что отделять и от чего отделять.

Comment: «когда в обществе много музыки» вклинилось в «что общество цельное»....

Comment: Именно так. Вклинилось, живет там и паразитирует.